# While writing unit test of method creating soapClient i am failing to mock local variables

Tags: java, unit-testing, soap, soap-client, spock

Below is my code...

```
HashMap<String, String> createSoapClient(JObject jObject, String requestId, String Id){
String url = environmentConfig.getSoapEndPoint();
try {
    SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();
    SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(soapMessage, url);
}...
```

I want to mock soapConnectionFactory and soapConnection objects but failed. I hope this issue is due to `SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance()` singleton method but i can't change it.
Here is what i have tried:

```
given:
environmentConfig.getSoapEndPoint() >> "https://endpointName"
when:
HashMap<String, String> map = service.createSoapClient(obj, "request-id", "abc")
then:
assert map != null
```

Comment: `SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();` The *singelton pattern* is the root of all evel. Add an *constructor parameter* for the SOAPConnectionFactory rather that getting it via static method access. Then you can easily substitute the real factory by a mock.

Comment: but i can't change SOAPConnectionFactory class.

Comment: You misuderstood the comment. There is no need to change the factory class from the JDK, but your own code using it. The concept is called dependency injection (google it, please). Basically it says that code should not create its own dependencies but get them injected, e.g. via constructor parameters, method parameters or setter methods. BTW, a good testing guideline is: If it is hard to mock dependencies, refactor your code to make it more testable.

Comment: Thanks kriegaex now i understood your point.